# Sum DF columns stored in nested dict

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, dictionary, iteration

I got a dictionary with 2 other dictionaries each storing 3 Dataframes {0: DataFrame, 1: DataFrame, 2: DataFrame}.

dict_results = {ID_1542: {0: DataFrame, 1: DataFrame, 2: DataFrame}, ID_8468: {0: DataFrame, 1: DataFrame, 2: DataFrame}}

Each DataFrame has the same size. 6 variables, 25 rows, for example

```
    A    B   ...   F
0   500  400       885.2
...
24  799  248       103
```

I'd like to sum all the values/rows from each DataFrame column 'B' for the dictionares ID_1542 and ID_8468.

I'd like to store the results in new single DataFrame with two columns ['ID_1542'] and ['ID_8468']
and 3 rows (each for every sum of DF0, DF1, DF2). How can i do that?

I tried it with...

```
for idx, df in dict_results.items():
    temp_list = []

    for key in df:
        temp_list.append(df[key]['B'].sum()/1000)
        SumsOfB = pd.DataFrame(temp_list, columns = [idx])
```

This gives me a DataFrame with column name ['ID_8468'] and the last 3 Sums. 
How can i get a DataFrame with two columns named ['ID_1542'] and ['ID_8468'] and the corresponding sums (meaning 3 rows (each for every sum of DF0, DF1, DF2))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ['ColFoo', 'Values']

dfA = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10], ['b', 11]], columns = cols) 
dfB = pd.DataFrame([['d', 12], ['e', 13]], columns = cols) 
dfC = pd.DataFrame([['g', 14], ['h', 15]], columns = cols) 
dfD = pd.DataFrame([['j', 16], ['k', 17]], columns = cols) 
dfE = pd.DataFrame([['m', 18], ['n', 19]], columns = cols) 
dfF = pd.DataFrame([['p', 20], ['q', 21]], columns = cols) 


# For example, the dfA is:
#   ColFoo   Values
#   ------   ------
#      a       10       
#      b       11


# Build dict_results
dict_results = {'ID_1542': {0: dfA, 1: dfB, 2: dfC}, 
                'ID_8468': {0: dfD, 1: dfE, 2: dfF}}
```

The FINAL result I think you are looking for:

```
   df    ID_1542  ID_8468
-------  -------  -------
    0       21        33       
    1       25        37
    2       29        41
```

So:

```py
# Dictionary to summarize data 
d = {}

# Loop over "Values":
# kf: Key father
# kc: Key child
for kf in dict_results:
    d[kf]={}
    for kc in dict_results[kf]:
        d[kf][kc] = dict_results[kf][kc]['Values'].sum()

# Convert dictionary to dataframe        
df_sum = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

# In case you want to have the index as a independent column
df_sum.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"df_kc"})
```